# Date as input in jsp page

Tags: jsp

I want to create an input field on my jsp page which takes a date as input. I want the field to have 3 different dropdowns for Date, Month and Year wherein date can have values from 1 to 31, Month can have January to December and Year can have 2018 to several years before. Please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having 3 combo boxes, you should use date time picker. By default JSP works with HTML 4, so do not forget to make your JSP HTML 5 Compatible. by writing

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <h2>Date Field</h2>
    <p>The <strong>input type="date"</strong> is used for input fields that should contain a date.</p>
    <p>Depending on browser support:<br>A date picker can pop-up when you enter the input field.<p>

    <form action="/abc.jsp">
      Birthday:
      <input type="date" name="bday">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

When you create a new JSP page, some code is generated automatically like this:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Edit second line. Keep second like code like this

Comment: Can you please let me know how to make my jsp HTML5 compatible. I tried using your code but still I am getting the date field as a text box.

Comment: I have updated answer please see. Also make sure you are running your web application in chrome browser or IE 11 +